# Weird behavior of first Row of a Grid Container

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

To get my head around front-end, I decided to create a simple calculator. It seemed like a good idea to use the `grid-layout` since the content is pretty well known upfront, won't change and since I wanted to be able to use different sized buttons as well vertically as horizontally.
With a 4x6 grid, I was able to lay out everything as I wanted.

To better visualize my issue, I have created a [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/hanskre/full/WNQmZMM) for it. My issue is that although I'm using a `grid-layout`, the row-height is different for the first row.

Here's the `CSS`:

```
.calculator-grid-container {
      height: 70vh;
      width: 60vw;
      max-width: 50vh;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 3px;
      border-color: white;
      background-color:#2e323a;
      border-radius: 1%;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px whitesmoke;
      /* grid container config */
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
      grid-gap: 0px;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

I'm setting the class on a `div` and rendering the buttons and the display inside of it:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className='calculator-grid-container'>
        <Display current={this.state.current} formula={this.state.formula}></Display>

        <Button name='AC' handleButtonPressed={this.handleButtonPressed}></Button>
        <Button name='/' handleButtonPressed={this.handleButtonPressed}></Button>
        <Button name='*' handleButtonPressed={this.handleButtonPressed}></Button>

        <Button name='1' handleButtonPressed={this.handleButtonPressed}></Button>
        <Button name='2' handleButtonPressed={this.handleButtonPressed}></Button>
        <Button name='3' handleButtonPressed={this.handleButtonPressed}></Button>
        <Button name='-' handleButtonPressed={this.handleButtonPressed}></Button>

        <Button name='4' handleButtonPressed={this.handleButtonPressed}></Button>
        <Button name='5' handleButtonPressed={this.handleButtonPressed}></Button>
        <Button name='6' handleButtonPressed={this.handleButtonPressed}></Button>
        <Button name='+' handleButtonPressed={this.handleButtonPressed}></Button>

        <Button name='7' handleButtonPressed={this.handleButtonPressed}></Button>
        <Button name='8' handleButtonPressed={this.handleButtonPressed}></Button>
        <Button name='9' handleButtonPressed={this.handleButtonPressed}></Button>
        <Button name='=' handleButtonPressed={this.handleButtonPressed}></Button>

        <Button name='0' handleButtonPressed={this.handleButtonPressed}></Button>
        <Button name='.' handleButtonPressed={this.handleButtonPressed}></Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

And on the buttons, I'm using the `flex-layout` to center the text:

```
.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center; /* align vertical */
}
```

And of course to let them span accordingly, for example:

```
.AC-button {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}
```

Now, my issue is with the first row, which is a `div`-container with two `p`-elements:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className='display'>
        <p className='formula'>
          {this.props.formula}
        </p>
        <p className='current' id='display'>
          {this.props.current}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Their CSS:

```
.display {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: digital;
  padding: 5px 10px 0 0;
  /* grid config */
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 5;
  /* flex-layout inside the div to align the p-elements */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: right;
}

.formula {
  opacity: 0.5;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word; 
}

.current {
  font-size: 46px;
}
```

Problems with above aproache:
1. The height of the first row (the `.display`) seems to differ a lot from all the other rows. I want all the rows to have exactly same height.
2. The size of the `.display` seems to vary with the `font-size` of `.formula` and `.current`, I don't want it to grow when I change the `font-size` of the containing `p`-elements.
3. The size of the .display varies radically if the `.formula` element is empty (i.e. `''`). It seems like the `p`-element would be non-existent if it is empty. I don't want the size to vary if the `p` element is empty.

Maybe I'm missing something. Can someone help?

Screenshot with empty `.formula` (`p-elem = ''`), notice the height:
[image]

Screenshot with non-empty `.formula`, notice the different height:
[image]

Comment: The extra height is because of the default P tag top and bottom margins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution, which does solve all the above mentioned issues (1. all rows have fixed and equal hight, 2. the height of the `.display-div` does not vary regardless of the content of the `.formula` `p`-tag and 3. regardless of the `font-size` set on them).

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
```

This is creating 6 `rows`, each occupying 1 equal fraction of the available free space (one caveat on using `fr`: the free space is calculated after any non-flexible items).

So apparently the thing that I was missing was actually specifying the fact that I wanted all the rows to be of equal height.

Thank you @arieljuod for pointing out in the comment on the default `margins` on the `p`-tag!

```
p {
  margin-top: 0; /* remove default margins */
  margin-bottom: 0;  /* remove default margins */
  min-height: 25%; /* avoid dropping height to 0 for empty p-tags */
}
```

I noticed that the `p`-tag still collapsed to a `height` of 0 when when it had no content, even though the `row-height` did not change anymore. This still lead to a kind of unclean behavior where the lower `p`-element was 'jumping' up when the upper `p`-element was reset to occupy the available `height` and then back down on a button pressed when the upper `p`-tag `height` was getting set and hence the `height` reclaimed by the upper `p`-element.

To avoid that, I added `min-height: 25%` to the `p`-tag,  so now the `height` is never dropping below 25% of the available space which avoids the above mentioned behavior of the lower `p`-element.

Here's how this now looks like:

[image]